# How do I publish an ASP.NET application using SCP from MonoDevelop on Windows 7

Tags: c#, ssh, monodevelop, fuse

I am using MonoDevelop on Windows and only get the "Local Filesystem" target for web deployment. According to this site: http://monodevelop.com/documentation/creating_asp.net_projects, I need FUSE filesystem to get an "SSH (FUSE)" target type.

[image: http://monodevelop.com/@api/deki/files/359/=AspNetWebDeployNew.png?size=webview]

Has anyone got this to run on windows? What are the steps I need to take?

Answer (score 1):

The SSH (FUSE) deployment handler uses the `sshfs` FUSE filesystem to temporarily mount the remove filesytem into a local directory, then uses normal file operations to deploy into that directory.

As far as I know, FUSE does not run on Windows, so this feature cannot work on Windows as-is.

MonoDevelop now includes NSch, a port of the JSch SSH library, use for git support. This library supports SFTP, so it would be possible for an interested party to write a new deployment handler that would use that to do the deployment directly. I'd be happy to provide guidance to anyone interested in doing so.

Comment: thanks. It turns out, XSP2 and mod_mono both want the bin folder in different places, so I'll be deploying manually for the moment. meh. I'm a developer - how hard can it be to script this ;)

Answer (score 1):

As mhutch has said, this doesn't work on Windows, because Windows doesn't support Fuse.

However, you could install Dokan + Dokan SSHFS. 
Then you'd need to download the monodevelop sourcecode, check for Windows, and add functionaly to mount via the dokan command line. 
Then issue a pull-request on Github.